# Listing filenames that contain, but does not begin or end with a certain character sequence

Tags: wildcards, command

I want to list all filenames that include "2022" but exclude those that begin with it or end with it. What commands would work for this?

Comment: Maybe `find ! -name '2022*' ! -name '*2022'`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon That would also include files that don't contain `2022`.

Comment: @NasirRiley ah, that's true and one but ugly solution to that (I think) is: `find ! -name '2022*' ! -name '*2022' -name '*2022*'`

Answer (score 1):

This `find` command will do it:

```
find . -name '*2022*' ! \( -name '2022*' -o -name '*2022' \)
```

It will first match the files that contain `2022` anywhere and then proceed to not match those that contain `2022` at the beginning or end.

In the environment where I used this, all of the `*` have to be escaped either with single quotes or a `\`.

You can also use this command to declare every condition separately but I find the first to be more convenient:

```
find . -name '*2022*' ! -name '2022*' ! -name '*2022'
```

Keep in mind that that will descend to the entire depths of the directory. To limit it to the cwd:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*2022*' ! \( -name '2022*' -o -name '*2022' \)
```